# Proces group id with ps command

Tags: unix, process, ps

I tried ps with different kinds of switches e.g. -A, aux, ef, and so forth but I cannot seem to find the right combination of switches that will tell me the Process ID (PID), Parent Process ID (PPID), Process Group ID (PGID), and the Session ID (SID) of a process in the same output.

Comment: Better ask on http://supersuser.com Also I don't understand how the subject corresponds to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$ ps  xao pid,ppid,pgid,sid | head
  PID  PPID  PGID   SID
    1     0     1     1
    2     0     0     0
    3     2     0     0
    6     2     0     0
    7     2     0     0
   21     2     0     0
   22     2     0     0
   23     2     0     0
   24     2     0     0

If you want to see the process' name as well, use this:

$ ps  xao pid,ppid,pgid,sid,comm | head
  PID  PPID  PGID   SID COMMAND
    1     0     1     1 init
    2     0     0     0 kthreadd
    3     2     0     0 ksoftirqd/0
    6     2     0     0 migration/0
    7     2     0     0 watchdog/0
   21     2     0     0 cpuset
   22     2     0     0 khelper
   23     2     0     0 kdevtmpfs
   24     2     0     0 netns
```